# Why does the text go off the grid? Element UI

Tags: css, element-ui

I am using this Element UI component
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox#checkbox-group

Basically to group checkbox, but the detail I have is that when using it in the grid, it leaves the div

```
 <el-row>
          <el-form-item>
            <el-checkbox-group v-model="packageForm.premises.secundaryClassDefinitions" :disabled="isDisabled">
              <el-row>
                <el-col 
                   class="check-element" 
                   :span="12"
                   v-for="(item, index) in primaryClassCode" :key="index">
                    <el-checkbox 
                      :label="item.value"
                      :value="item.code">
                    </el-checkbox>>                
                </el-col>
              </el-row>
            </el-checkbox-group>
          </el-form-item>  
        </el-row>
```

visually it looks like this:
[image]

The left side is a checkbox and the right side is the other checkbox, so as you will see the text on the left side leaves the line and goes to the other side.

[image]

What is in red is the entire  div and in yellow is the  that contains the text, you can see that it comes out of the box.
What could I do about it?
I have applied the different properties to the css of the `el-checkbox__label` class

```
width: 50%;
display:inline-block;
float:left
word-break: break-word
```

But they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "display: flex" for parent and "flex: 1" for child. Like:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
}
```